# Protobuf parse text

Tags: ruby, protocol-buffers

I have the following protobuf text and I am using google-protobuf to parse it but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
# HELP Type about service.
# TYPE gauge
metadata_server1{namespace="default",service="nginx"} 1
metadata_server2{namespace="default",service="operator"} 1
metadata_server3{namespace="default",service="someservice"} 1
...
```

Whenever I try to decode it, I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/protobuf-3.8.3/lib/protobuf/decoder.rb:21:in `decode_each_field'
```

This is how I am trying to decode it:

```
class Metrics < ::Protobuf::Message
  required :string, :namespace, 1
  required :string, :value, 2
  required :string, :map, 3
end

class Message < ::Protobuf::Message
  repeated Metrics, :metrics, 1
end

data = get_data('http://localhost:8080/')

parsed_data = Metrics.decode(data)
puts parsed_data.metrics //does not work
```

Does anyone know how I can parse this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not a Protobuf. Protobuf is a binary format, not text, so it would not be human-readable like the data you are seeing. Technically, Protobuf has an alternative text representation used for debugging, but your data is not that format either.

Instead, your data appears to be Prometheus text format, which is not a Protobuf format. To parse this, you will need a Prometheus text parser. Usually, only Prometheus itself consumes this format, so not a lot of libraries for parsing it are available (whereas there are lots of libraries for creating it). The format is pretty simple, though, and you could probably parse it with a suitable regex.

Some servers which export Prometheus metrics also support exporting it in an alternative Protobuf-based format. If your server supports that, you can request it by sending the header:

```
Accept: application/vnd.google.protobuf; proto=io.prometheus.client.MetricFamily; encoding=delimited
```

If you send that in the request, you *might* get a Protobuf-based format back, if the server supports it. Note that the Protobuf format is deprecated and removed in Prometheus 2, so fewer servers are likely to support it these days.

If your server does support this format, note that the result is still not a plain Protobuf. Rather, it is a collection of Protobufs in "delimited" format. Each Protobuf is prefixed by a varint-encoded length ("varint" is Protobuf's variable-width integer encoding). In C++ or Java, there are "parseDelimitedFrom" functions you can use to parse this format, but it looks like Ruby does not have built-in support currently.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Using the correct `Accept` header, I was able to get the protobuf format. I then used Prometheus Ruby client library to parse the data.